# TV from Israel on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, time-zone

If one owns a restaurant that features news from Israel, can he allow that to be on  on Friday afternoon when it is Shabbos in Israel?
In other words  if a Jew may benefit before Shabbat from mealcha done by a Jew living somewhere else when it was Shabbat there.